# Database permissions for Python Desktop application

Tags: python, authentication, server, client

I recently started developing a Desktop python application and I would like to know how more expert people would handle this issue.

I used to develop (about 5-10 years ago) web applications in the past using PHP + MySQL and there, since the code/program is located on the server where the user doesn't have access (except the web page), I could simply store the user/group permissions in the database in a table say users, users_groups, users_permissions, and so on. I would then check at every page load if the user had the right to access that page / update that record in the database.

With a desktop application where the user has access to the executable (which can relatively easy be decompiled to source code, being written in Python) the approach will likely be quite different.

Since MySQL has forked into MariaDB and is not so actively developed anymore, PostgreSQL looked promising to start. I thought about creating different users on PostgreSQL level and letting PostgreSQL handle the permissions (instad of my application handling them directly).

However, this only allows tuning of the permissions down to the table level. A user will be allowed to create/delete/update records in a table, however no further control is available. AFAIK you cannot tell "let this user only update his own records" or "this user can only delete the records from this group", or "users from group X can only update their own records while users from group Y can update everybody's records".

My understanding as how to handle this kind of issue would be to put some kind of middleware application between the user and the database, located on the server, such as:
Desktop application <-----> Server-side application permissions handler <-----> Database

Where server-side permission handler could be as simple as adding a "WHERE user=..." to each query as well as much more advanced stuff (first check user permissions stored in the database, based on that decide if letting user execute the query or reject it). I think this is a common problem for all desktop applications and would therefore expect that such a server-side application already exist. Am I missing something obvious or maybe PostgreSQL allows for more detailed fine-tuning?

Thank you for all your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right. It is never a good idea having a client access directly a database. Take a look a Django https://www.djangoproject.com and https://www.django-rest-framework.org 
This would be the the basis for your server side. You would handle here business logic, authentication, authorization. The client should basically present the data within the UI and delegate all the decision making to the server.

Here you can find a step by step tutorial about how to implement a REST api with user authentication in Django. https://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-authentication-tutorial/

Comment: When I looked into python web frameworks for another project (which didn't start unfortunately) I didn't like Django that much. I was more attracted by Pyramid framework. But I'm a bit confused... I though web framework were for web pages (applications). Here it would be more like a Middleware server application. Or you would just use say the permissions/account/roles module of the web framework for this task? Why would a bad idea letting the desktop application connect directly to the database server? Password attacks? I guess you could mitigate that with ip tables and fail2ban

Comment: Django or any other decent application framework offers an ORM, a set of services, like authentication and authorization, and RESTful interfaces. In modern web application they are mostly used as a server side layer while the frontend is build using Angular or React. When building a client side app, you must always assume that the user can sidestep your client and connect directly to the server, so all the business logic, security, etc. etc. must be built server-side. A modern app framework offers so much more than a database to do that.

Comment: Building on top of a db, you would be using a lot of db procedures to encapsulate the logic. Most of your time would be spent going around the idiosyncrasies of a procedural language not conceived for a modular application structure. The rest of the time you would be reinventing the wheel. Alternatively you could build all your logic in the desktop and then you would have one big security and process compliance hole, if someone connects directly to the database. Leave alone that if you ever want to build a web version you must reimplement all the logic from the start.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately it's still quite unclear on how to code the server-side "manager" as well as the Desktop client app. Would you have a more complete example that you could link to? I don't even know which keywords would best describe what I want to achieve ... I would like to do it with Pyramid in the end because it seems to be quite flexible for both small and big projects, but I wouldn't mind an example in another framework

Comment: I have not developed anything in Pyramid but it looks like it lacks everything that would compel me to adopt it (db migrations, ORM, rest library, user model) while providing a MVC which is completely useless if you are developing a server api. I have added a link to a tutorial.

Comment: OK I'll try do to this in django then, I guess the amount of documentation is quite big given the popularity of this framework. And the turial you linked is top notch, thank you :). I tried to give you upvote but unfortunately I don't have enough rep. points to do that :(